# SSRS Login Loop CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online

Trying to connect SSRS with CRM Dynamics.

Connection string : prod2021.crm4.dynamics.com

user & passwords are good.

[image: Log in area]

I'm getting those following 2 screens and then the login screen from above again.

[image: Looking for organization]

[image: Recognize Login Request]

I'm stuck in a loop with those and can't connect to my organization.

How can I solve this?

I know that I can ignore it and continue working without it but then I'll have to create all the fields by my self and debugging it would be much difficult.

Comment: What happens when you check that “Display list of available orgs”? I can see the default org it’s trying to connect is prodware, is that same as prod2021? Do you have the latest report authoring extensions installed?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. Someone told me its because the trials doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest report authoring extensions installed?

If yes, Try this a workaround until Report Authoring Extension for v9 is available:

- On the machine where Visual Studio is installed, open regedit
- Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
- Create a **DWORD** key - Name: **SchUseStrongCrypto** - Value: **1**

Comment: I'll try this at work once I'm there. On vacation for the week.